# Is there a way to determine if a type is a Scala one or a JS one in Scala.JS?

Tags: scala.js

In Scala JS is there a way to determine if a value is Scala one or a native js one?

```
object Bar
case class Foo(x: Int)

def isAScalaType(x: Any) : Boolean = {/* What is the implementation of this function */}

isAScalaType(js.Dynamic.literal(Hello="World")) // returns false

isAScalaType(Foo(1)) // returns true
isAScalaType(Bar) // returns true

//Wrappers such as Int / Double / String etc should also return true:
isAScalaType("abc") // true
isAScalaType(123) // true
isAScalaType(1.0) // true
```

(This question was originally asked in the gitter chat room)

Answer (score 2):

The suggested method is to call .getClass on the value and see if it is null

e.g.

`def isAScalaType(x: Any) : Boolean = x.getClass != null`